# $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of real numbers, is $\sum \frac {a_n}{1+|a_n|}$ also convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of real numbers, then is $\sum \dfrac {a_n}{1+|a_n|}$ also convergent? I have tried Abel's, Dirichlet's test; nothing's working.

Comment: Since $f(x)=x/(1+|x|)$ is not linear in any neighborhood of $0$, the answer is negative.

Comment: How could this be false when each term of the second series is less than or equal to the term in the first?

Comment: @ElliotG If $a_n$ is non-negative, then the statement is true but the comparison test doesn't give anything for general series.

Comment: @levap thanks; I thought I must be missing something obvious

Comment: Statement is false, a simple counterexample: $$a_n = 
\begin{cases} 
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},   & n = 3k+1 \text{ or } 3k+2\\
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k}}, & n = 3k
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @achille hui That's worth writing up as an answer.

Comment: Achille hui i tried your example but it not work. Can you explain more 3.